# Amazon EC2 Local Files

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is it possible to run computations on EC2 instances with files from my local computer? I have data on the order of multiple TB, which would cost a lot and take a long time to upload. Perhaps there's an interface to access files across machines? I couldn't find any in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean w/o transferring at all, no. It is not possible.
In order to work over some data, a process must have it in its memory space. If your process is in EC2, then the data must be in the memory space of that process in EC2. Whatever you end up doing, say use sshfs, the data will always end up being transferred.

If you want to avoid having to transfer at first and only have the process use the files as if they are local, then you can use nfs or sshfs for example.